# Tinymce Editor in web application

Tags: tinymce

I want to use the Tinymce Editor in my web application. I have a text area on it and I want to submit the data of that text area to the next page. That page should display the data it received. Can you give any suggestions how I can do this.

Comment: You really have to explain more.. what are u using to write your web application? Do u want to store the data and etc..

Answer (score 1):

You should start with this [instructions](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Installation).
Displaying html content is very simple. You need to place the written text one of yor pages receives on that page - that is all.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think of TinyMCE is as a special textarea. Just like you can submit data from a textarea and retrieve the content via request variables, you can do the same for a TinyMCE editor instance.

In your front-end code, you would have something like this:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas"
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="show.php">
    <p>     
        <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="15">Content in TinyMCE</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</form>
...
```

Then, in your show.php page, you would retrieve the content like you would retrieve a textarea value:

```
<?php

...
echo $_POST['content'];
...
```

It's about as simple as that to retrieve the data and display it in your page. Of course, you would need to take security precautions in displaying data that is entered by an end user. Also, this is assuming you are using PHP as the back-end technology; but, the principles carry over to any technology.

And, consult the TinyMCE [documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php) for detailed instructions and information on advanced use cases.

Comment: Stephen-thanks for your helpful post which works fine (& see Thariama's comment with link below to TinyMCE site & instructions).This saves the textarea content to php file-what I want is to find how to save it to a new text file? Any help grateful received..:-)