# Tinymce Editor in web application

Tags: tinymce

How can i extract text area data in TinyMce Editor on submit button and save it to text file .Give function to save extracted data in file...Also how we can add submit button in editor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tinymce Editor in web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433357/tinymce-editor-in-web-application)

Comment: -1 this is question number five or six of the same kind - please stop fooling us!

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE is a JavaScript plugin to convert textareas to allow rich-text formatting. As such, the content of the TinyMCE editor is available in the array submitted to the server. In PHP, this is the $_POST array. I'd have to look up what it is for ASP.NET, but I think it is the Request array.

You really shouldn't be attempting to have TinyMCE doing any direct posting. Create a submit input element (either in HTML or using the equivalent .NET control) that will submit the form. As for the second part of your question... you really need to include more information. If you're using PHP, here's how you can write to a file:

```
$path="path-to-file.extension";
$filenum=fopen( $path,"w" );
fwrite( $filenum,$data );
fclose( $filenum );
```